Почему в POSIX принято начинать имена разделяемых ресурсов со слеша?
Хотелось бы понять, почему во многих учебных материалах, примерах и т. д. для задания имени семафора или разделяемой памяти используется строка, начинающаяся со слеша? Например вызов
auto sem = sem_open("/test", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);

приводит к созданию файла ресурса /dev/shm/test
Я проверил, что тот же самый вызов, но без слеша в имени
auto sem = sem_open("test", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);

тоже приводит к созданию файла /dev/shm/test
На первый взгляд, никакой разницы не заметно, оба созданных таким образом семафора обеспечивают корректное взаимодействие между процессами. Это действительно так и подобное именование это просто старая традиция (откуда она пошла, если так?), или же есть какая-то невидимая на первый взгляд разница между созданными такими способами разделяемыми ресурсами?

В POSIX написано такое: «If name begins with the  character, then processes calling sem_open() with the same value of name shall refer to the same semaphore object, as long as that name has not been removed. If name does not begin with the  character, the effect is implementation-defined.»

То есть, если я в разных процессах создам два семафора с именем "test" без слеша, то есть вероятность, что это будут два разных независимых семафора?

"implementation-defined" значит в руководстве на компилятор написано как оно будет себя вести. Поэтому лучше придерживаться варианта со слэшом.
